# Exclude files of my release .apk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android Studio application that depends on android-library project.
This android-library project contains some native libraries .so, but I want that in my final apk not appears some of these .so.

How can I do this? I add this code in the build.gradle of my app but files continue appearing:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/armeabi/a.so'
}
```

Thanks

Comment: will your app work without these .so files?

Comment: yes, cause this android-library is for more applications, and I want to avoid that apk has unused resorces

Comment: so basically you want to strip down library to the functions which are useful to you. is my understanding correct?

Comment: Do you wan to have platform specific apk , hence removing the .so files which are not meant for a platform ?

Answer (score -1):

It should work if you wrap the `packagingOptions` within the `android` stanza like this:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/a.so'
    }
}
```